# Merging final states of a DFA

Tags: automata, dfa

Can we merge or combine all of the final states of a DFA which has more then one final states? Will it produce another equivalent DFA?
Till now, i just figure out that in some cases, merging all the final states of a DFA can produce another NFA which maybe equivalent with the foregoing DFA.
THANK YOU

Answer (score 1):

You may only merge/combine states which are equivalent. States are equivalent, if the language recognized by them is identical. The recognized language is the set of strings which leads from the given state to a stop state.

Consider the regular expression `a+|b`. After the sequence `aa` the DFA is in a stop state, call it s1. It must have an outgoing transition on `a` to another stop state, which may be itself.

On the other hand, on the input `b`, the DFA is also in a stop state, call it s2. This can not have any outgoing transition which will ever end up in a stop state, because otherwise some string starting with `b` would be recognized, which is not permitted by `a+|b`.

Consequently s1 and s2 are not equivalent and can not be merged.

You noticed correctly, however, that we can always add an epsilon transition from all stop states to a unique, new stop state. But the result is an NFA, not a DFA anymore.